# ios: how to get IntentHandler Confirm response in UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, callkit, sirikit, customintents

I am developing an INStartCallIntent ... I want to invoke CallKit from confirm method of IntentHandler. but

```
func confirm(intent: INStartCallIntent) async -> INStartCallIntentResponse {
    //    CallManager.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    //    CallManager.sharedInstance().startCall(withPhoneNumber: "+923224123443")
        
        let userActivity = NSUserActivity(activityType: String(describing: INStartCallIntent.self))
        return INStartCallIntentResponse(code: .continueInApp, userActivity: userActivity)
    }
```

shows error **Cannot find 'CallManager' in scope**

[image]

while its in here

[image]

I implemented AppDelegate function but could not invoke it from IntentHandler.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleIntent:(INIntent *)intent completionHandler:(void (^)(INIntentResponse * _Nonnull))completionHandler{

//    if(intent == INStartCallIntent){
//        NSLog(@"Hey ... here it is");
//    }
}
```

**CallManager.h** added in project's **bridging header** file

[image]

Seems like its not accessible in **IntentExtension**.

CallManager Files are in **kBeaconDemo_ios** while they are not accessible in **CallHomeAwayData** IntentExtension.

[image]

How can I call CallManager after confirm? Please suggest

Comment: Did you add `CallManager.h` to the `*Project*-Bridging-Header.h` file? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-do-i-call-objective-c-code-from-swift?rq=1

Comment: I edited the question with bridging header info .. CallManager is not accessible in IntentExtension while its accessible in rest of project both objective-c and swift files.

Comment: I believe each target gets its own bridging header. Update the other target(s) as needed to use the bridging header.